# how to read multiple value length in javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

I am working on a barcode scanner and currently have a problem where I need the barcode to read 2 different value lengths, currently I have it set to submit the value at 9 length.

```
          <span>
                <input type="text" id="IC-input" name="IC" onkeyup="autofill(this.value)" placeholder="Enter your IC Number" required maxlength="12">
                <label><button type="button" id="theButton" onclick="theButtonIsPressed()">Submit</button></label>
          </span>

        function autofill(value){
        console.log("Autofill:"+value)
        //console.log(9 digits);
        button = document.getElementById("theButton");
        if(value.length == 9){
            console.log('form is ready to submit');
            theButtonIsPressed(value);
        } 
    }
```

now i need it to read from 12 value as well but it auto submits when the value hits 9 digits. I have tried OR function .

```
        function autofill(value){
        console.log("Autofill:"+value)
        //console.log(9 digits);
        button = document.getElementById("theButton");
        if(value.length == 12 || value.length == 9){
            console.log('form is ready to submit');
            theButtonIsPressed(value);
        } 
    }
```

i also tried the Else function

```
        function autofill(value){
        console.log("Autofill:"+value)
        //console.log(9 digits);
        button = document.getElementById("theButton");
        if(value.length == 12){
            console.log('form is ready to submit');
            theButtonIsPressed(value);
        } 
        else if(value.length == 9){
            theButtonIsPressed(value);
        }
    }
```

But it would always read the first 9 value and leave the 3 other value unread. Does anyone have a solution for this? Thank you in advance.

Comment: As I understand, your function is run on every change in the input field, right?

Comment: Yes, automatically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like you are listening to the keypress. Use a timer to cancel it. Basic idea of a debounce method.

```
var timer;
function autofill(value){
  if (timer) window.clearTimeout(timer);
  if(value.length === 9){
    timer = window.setTimeout( function () {
      processIt(value);
    }, 50);
  } else if(value.length === 12){
    processIt(value);
  } 
}

function processIt(value){
  console.log('here', value);
}
```

**BUT That is a bad solution.** Typically you set up the scanner to fire a tab or enter press so you know it is done. I would check to see if that is happening and listen for that instead. You can then just listen for that and you know the scanner is done.

```js
var inp = document.getElementById("barcode");
inp.addEventListener("keydown", function (evt) {
  if (["Tab", "Enter"].includes(evt.key)) {
    evt.preventDefault();
    console.log('scanner is done', evt.target.value);
  }
});
```

```html
<input type="text" id="barcode" />
```

Comment: Great idea, however, if someone is a slow typist or stops for any reason after entering 9 characters, it will processIt

Comment: Do you mean that the data is entered automatically from a device? Or does a user type it manually?

Comment: It is a device....It reads the barcode and types the value

Comment: If you have an input `<input type="text"`, it is shown on an HTML page, right?

Comment: I am trying to understand how it works. If a user uses the scanner, then the scanner is sending the whole message consisting of 9 or 12 characters, right? Or does it send the characters one by one?

Comment: It depends on the scanner. Sounds like OP's types each character. The correct way is what I put in the code. It should not care about the characters, just what the scanner types at the end.

Comment: Yes! This is exactly what i need, i just tried it and it works perfectly! Thank you so much for understanding by question and taking your time to help me out!

Comment: Just for some context, I needed the program to automatically submit the input value once it hits 9/12 value length.

Answer (score 1):

For a most common scene, the scanner will trigger such event one by one: focus, input character....input final 'Enter' character, so you have to take attention to the last event.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    window.addEventListener("load", function () {
        var ic = document.getElementById("IC-input");
        ic.addEventListener("focus", function (args) {
            ic.value = "";
        });
        ic.addEventListener("keyup", function (args) {
            if (args.key == "Enter") {
                autofill(ic.value);
            }
        });
    });
    function autofill(value) {
        console.log("Autofill:" + value)
        //console.log(9 digits);
        button = document.getElementById("theButton");
        if (value.length == 9) {
            console.log('form is ready to submit');
            theButtonIsPressed(value);
        }
    }
</script>
<span>
    <input type="text" id="IC-input" name="IC" onkeyup="input_keyup" placeholder="Enter your IC Number" required maxlength="12">
    <label><button type="button" id="theButton" onclick="theButtonIsPressed()">Submit</button></label>
</span>
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the autofill function runs to press the button as soon as the input box has 9 characters. It is because you are running the autofill function by the 'onkeyup' event listener attached to the input tag.

The solution is to run the autofill function after making sure there is a full length value intended. Good luck.